# mp4 videos are showing up as "corrupt" after uploading them to web server?

Tags: html5, video, ftp, uploading

I took a sample mp4 video from [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1425) and uploaded it to the web server via FileZilla. Once the file was on the web server navigating to it in a browser gives the error when viewed in Mozilla.

> Video can't be played because the file is corrupt

If you navigate to the URL in Chrome, you hear the audio but the video doesn't play.

If I download the video to my local machine from the web server the video won't load and I get errors saying it is corrupt. The file is fine before uploading.

I'm really confused about what is going on. I tried uploading a .mov file and I don't get this issue. The file uploads and runs fine (although I don't think .mov is supported by the HTML5 `<movie>` tag). I want to get the file in mp4 format.

Is this a known issue? Is this a browser issue or likely an ftp issue? I'm not really sure why this is happening.

**Note**

I have uploaded the sample file linked above from 2 different FTP clients and under Binary and ASCII uploads and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Hi Leigero, To attract better answers and less guessing from the community please edit your question and include important information such as the complete markup your using.

Comment: I think this is something to do with the format of the file and browser compatibility? I get the same if I simply link directly to the uploaded file in the browser. However, downloading and playing the file locally should work OK - providing you have the correct codecs installed on your machine. Does the original file from the Apple website play OK for you?

Comment: @bybe I'm not really using any markup. I'm just uploading the file to the web server root via FTP clients and navigating directly to the video file. Embedding the video on a page doesn't work because the video itself is corrupt.

Comment: "Does the original file from the Apple website play OK for you?" - This file is not "corrupt".

Comment: @w3d Yes, I stated in the question that the video plays fine before uploading it.

Comment: Well, you said it was "fine" - but when you download it, it is corrupt - this is very strange and a different issue, suggesting a problem with the file transfer. Is the file size the same? (But this isn't just a file transfer problem - since I can replicate the symptoms in Firefox and Chrome.)

Comment: @w3d The file downloads fine from apple's website, but after moving the file from the file-server back on to my PC it then doesn't work. The file sizes are identical (the corrupt file on the server and the working file on my machine).

Comment: How large is the average mp4 file?

Answer (score 1):

You may have an anti-virus or firewall program (like McAfee or Norton's) on your computer that is interfering with the File Transfer. Try disabling that and see if it works.